# Three 2D maps in a single 3D graph in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way to construct three 2D maps (three heat maps) in a
single 3D graph in the Gnuplot? I have three datasets (in matrix form) to plot as 2D maps in a single 3D graph: the first data in the XY plane, the second in XZ, and the last one in YZ. 
Thus I tried the (naive) code:

`set multiplot
   splot 'data_1' matrix u 1:2:3 w image
   splot 'data_2' matrix u 2:3:1 w image
   splot 'data_3' matrix u 3:2:1 w image
 unset multiplot`

but except for the 'data_1' map, all the others are out of scale. 
There is any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the `splot` command 4 pieces of information: the x, y, and the z coordinate, and the value for the color. For example, the script

```
set xyplane at -0.5
set xrange [-0.5:3.5]
set yrange [-0.5:3.5]
set zrange [-0.5:3.5]
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set ztics 1
set view 55,110
unset key
splot "data.dat" matrix  u 1:2:(-0.5):3 w image, \
      "" matrix u 1:(-0.5):2:3 w image, \
      "" matrix u (-0.5):1:2:3 w image
```

where `data.dat` is a data file in matrix format such as

```
1 2 3 2
4 5 6 5
7 8 9 8
4 5 6 5
```

gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @user8153, it is very simple. But for some reason (unknown to me) when the matrix row exceeds 4 the plot does not fit on the axes scale. Thus, based on your suggestion, I tried a modification. I used your script in a grid of color values (<z11> <z12> <z13>...\ <z21> <z22> <z23>...\). Now the output plot is in the axes scale.